# Get pdf page number by acrofield using itext7 with C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext7, acrofields

With iText7, I like to get pdf page number by form field but I can't find method or property of getting page number.

```
IDictionary<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.GetFormFields();
PdfFormField field = fields["fieldName"];
field.page <-- there is no property
```

I found this one:

```
PdfPage page = field.GetWidgets().First().GetPage();
```

But I have no idea of how to get page number from PdfPage.

It looks like iText5 has this one (in Java):

```
int page = form.getFieldPositions(name).get(0).page;
```

And how can I do it with iText 7 in C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially your problem is

> I have no idea of how to get page number from `PdfPage`.

The class `PdfDocument` has a method `GetPageNumber` for this:

```
/// <summary>Gets page number by page.</summary>
/// <param name="page">the page.</param>
/// <returns>page number.</returns>
public virtual int GetPageNumber(PdfPage page)
```

Thus, you can retrieve the page number of a page widget like this:

```
using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(formDocumentFile))
using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(reader))
{
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdf, true);
    PdfFormField field = form.GetField(fieldName);
    PdfPage page = field.GetWidgets().First().GetPage();
    int number = pdf.GetPageNumber(page);
    Console.WriteLine("Determined page number: {0}", number);
}
```

**Beware:**

- `field.GetWidgets().First()` implicitly assumes that the field has at least one widget. This is *not guaranteed*, there may be invisible fields without any widgets. In general you should check this.
- `....GetPage()` may return `null` if the widget annotation is not associated with any page (i.e. neither its own **P** entry is set nor is it referenced from any current page). In general you should check this.